# How to update dependencies in docker using poetry?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, python-poetry

I am trying to update a dependency in docker using poetry, I have added

```
RUN poetry update
RUN poetry install -n
```

in `Dockerfile` but it doesn't update the package. There is an import error with an older version of tortoise ORM, which requires an upgrade (verified by running the project without docker and with virtualenv and with the newer package) which persists with the changes to the Dockerfile.

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7


RUN pip install poetry
# RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# for poetry
RUN mkdir -p /app/app/
RUN touch /app/app/__init__.py


RUN poetry update
RUN poetry install -n


COPY ./app /app/app

EXPOSE 8000
```

my Dockerfile for reference.

Comment: "docker image prune" to blow away build cache and force the update. A better way to do it would be to explicitly specify versions in dockerfile.

Comment: What does `but it doesn't update the package` exactly mean?

Comment: @atline I have updated the question. Please do check.

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue with the dockerfile in question ... You surely miss something in the post to let folk to help you.